# How is browser able to use typescript file directly in Vite index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, vite

Recently I've been playing around with Vite. One thing that intrigues me is that it's ability to use typescript file directly in the index.html, e.g.

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
```

From the docs, I understand that Vite will transpile the original code from Typescript into Javascript (I inspected that the contents of `main.ts` are indeed transformed). But how can the browser run the Javascript code inside a `*.ts` file?

I tried to replicate it by creating a simple static server with an `index.html` containing the script tag like above. Yet, the browser will throw an error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

So how is this possible with Vite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But how can the browser run the Javascript code inside a *.ts file?

The JavaScript isn't in a `*.ts` file.

It is a resource, with a `Content-Type: text/javascript` response header, retrieved with a URL. The path of that URL only matters in so far as it tells the server what to look for. The browser doesn't care what letters are in it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The accepted answer is actually correct, as OP wasn't wondering what Vite does during *Production* builds but rather *Development* builds, which is that *Development* serves the transpiled results from memory (modifying `Content-Type` headers to server the right filetype, overriding file extensions hinting as necessary) while *Production* persistently changes URLs in generated artifacts.

My answer below explains what happens with Vite inputs during final, *Production*-mode transpilations, while the accepted answer explains how Vite gets away with transpiling files in-memory and modifying content headers to serve the in-memory transpiled files during *Development*-mode.

---

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think the answer that has been accepted doesn't actually match what was being questioned. I think the OP is wondering how you can refer to a "TypeScript" file in a Vite project's HTML root file (`index.html`) in order to transpile and run the referenced TypeScript code. An example being:

```html
<script type="module" src="./index.ts"></script>
```

---

TL;DR is that the browser never runs TypeScript code -- Vite transforms the URL above into something like:

```html
<script type="module" src="/index.[content_hash].js"></script>
```

> ...how can the browser run the Javascript code inside a *.ts file?

It (fortunately) doesn't have to. You partially answered your own question here:

> ...Vite will transpile the original code from Typescript into Javascript.

The browser is *not* being served raw TypeScript directly. Not only does Vite transform your assets, it also transforms your `index.html`'s links to any other external resources.

Try running `npm run build` or `vite build`, and then visit your output directory and inspect the generated `index.html` file yourself.

---

A "JavaScript-first" module bundler (like Webpack) creates a "dependency graph" of your modules. Basically, you provide an entry point, and the bundler traverses all imports (recursively) and does fancy things (i.e. bundling, tree-shaking, and any other transformation).

Vite, on the other hand, is what I'd call an "HTML-first" bundler. Where Webpack would opt to use JavaScript files (and sometimes other files) as entry points, Vite allows for HTML files to be an entry point. The same thing happens here, with the difference that instead of JavaScript imports, Vite instead traverses things like a `link` tag's `href` attribute, or an `img` tag's `src` attribute.

In both cases, once asset bundling and transformation has occurred, the dependency graph generally looks different -- and file types themselves may have changed. For example, multiple files merged together would no longer require multiple imports, and TypeScript files may now be JavaScript files. Bundlers account for that by dynamically changing import URLs and strategy based on the context.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The accepted answer addresses my question. Your answer is referring to the condition when Vite bundles for production, where the script url in index.html becomes `index.[content_hash].js`. In dev mode, the script url is still pointing to the `index.ts`. You can try to inspect the script tag in the DOM when you are in the dev server. Vite uses a completely different approach between its dev server (no bundling) and production (with bundling).

Comment: Ah! You're right! I considered writing a small aside about `mode: development` in Vite, but I didn't read you specifying a mode in your question. I figured it'd be a given that the processes that happen in production happen (almost) exactly the same as they do in development, but, instead of persisting the transpiled results in storage, they only happen *in-memory*. Which is why, as the selected answer pointed out, the `webpack-dev-server` can simply override the `Content-Type` header of what would be a `*.ts` file and instead serve it as a JavaScript file.